# Creating websites with Node.js

Tags: javascript, html, css, http, node.js

Hello I am wondering where to start on making websites width node.js. I did the hello world tutorial and have a working http server. But my question is if it is possible to run javascript server-side for lets say an onclick event? of how to put css in the webpage.

Thanks

Mkaveli

Comment: reading list: expressj.com, http://learnboost.github.com/stylus/, socket.io, nowjs.com, https://github.com/substack/dnode

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Eventhough you have javascript running on your server, events like onClick are still clientside.

Just because the server-side language is javascript doesnt mean you have control over client-side events. If you want actions to happen on the server at an onclick event, consider making the element a regular anchor, or use AJAX to make a call directly to the server.

Comment: ok, are there any good tutorials about making a website with node js and ajax?

Comment: If you're from the PHP world or similar, think of Node as a combination of Apache (as the web server) and PHP (the server side language that processes requests).  You send Ajax requests to the server from Javascript, the main difference being that you're also handling the request in Javascript rather than PHP.  As others have mentioned, Express is a good higher-level framework for creating websites.

Comment: ok i get that but what i dont know is how i set it all up. How do i load the html, css and javascript. I searched on google but could't find really any good tutorials on this.

Comment: Check out Express docs here for serving css, js files etc. via the middleware: http://expressjs.com/guide.html#middleware. You put the files in the /public folder.  For serving HTML you create views with templates as explained here: http://expressjs.com/guide.html#view-rendering

Answer (score 7):

you should try a node.js web framework such as [ExpressJs](http://expressjs.com/)

Answer (score 2):

Try to look at node.js web/middleware frameworks such as [connect](http://senchalabs.github.com/connect/) or [express](http://expressjs.com/). Especially express is preferred web framework with higher level abstraction and features including routing, views, template engines and other stuff.

Answer (score 2):

I know I'm a bit late but you still may want to have a look at this or at least it should help others.

I've collected informations and tutorials for beginners as well as useful frameworks and modules at http://www.quietwrite.com/writing/62732/node-dot-js-resources

Hope it helps.